# Base64 decoding failed for Google Speech API

Tags: android, google-speech-api, google-apis-explorer

I tried to send a POST request to https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize using the JSON and the code fragment below. Somehow google responsed that fail to decoding Base 64 in my request.

{
  "config": {
      "encoding": "LINEAR16",
      "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
      "languageCode": "ja-JP",
      "maxAlternatives": 5,
      "profanityFilter": false
  },
  "audio": {
    "content": "ZXCVBNM"
  },
}

```
    String pcmFilePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/voice8K16bitmono.pcm";
    File rawFile = new File(pcmFilePath);
    byte[] rawData = new byte[(int) rawFile.length()];
    DataInputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(rawFile));
        int readResult = input.read(rawData);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (input != null) {
        input.close();
    };

    String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(rawData, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String completePostBody = postBody.replace("ZXCVBNM" , base64);
```

"code": 400,
                                                                                                            "message": "Invalid value at 'audio.content' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for \"...

Does anyone have any suggestion ?

Comment: Essentially, what it says in the message. `ZXCVBNM` is invalid (incomplete) base64-encoding (it partially decodes to `epò` but is incomplete). Base-64 encodes every three characters of source (binary) data into 4 characters of encoded data. You only have seven characters so is incomplete (and also suspiciously short for any type of audio representation).

Comment: I realised later that you're replacing `ZXCVBNM` with what is meant to be your file content (I don't know Android enough to _know_ that your code is reading the file correctly or not). However, the point remains that what Google is receiving isn't valid base-64.  Try logging what you're actually sending in the payload to see if it makes sense. (Or, conceivably, Googole isn't expecting base64 (the link is giving 404 for me).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I send the POST request following this document: https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize. May be the link you are trying to access isn't made for browser. Here is the logging I actually sending in the pay load http://www.mediafire.com/file/9qzxyzexlxc7jr1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to get the result from Google Speech API.

It was documented that the Base 64 encoding should not have line-wrapping
Link: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/base64-encoding

Changing from `Base64.DEFAULT` to `Base64.NO_WRAP` worked in my case.
Also the pcm file should be LSB

Comment: That makes sense (once you're aware of it), although the docs you link don't make the requirement obvious (it's only really mentioned in the Linux example). I suspect using `encodeToString()` (which seems a reasonable thing to do) as opposed to a `byte[]` as they do in their Java example is part of the issue -- its default is obviously to line-wrap, presumably for inclusion in an email or the like.

Comment: @ZodiacLeo123 can you elaborate your answer? I am stuck with this problem too. What do you mean with "should not have line-wrapping Link". I noticed that in my base64 there are some symbol like, `'+'`, `'='`, `'\n'` and `'/'`. Is that the problem? And should all file encoded in LSB?

Comment: "Should not have line-wrapping link" is a sentence that was quoted from Google document. Actually I used library in Android Studio to get the base 64 encoded done for me. Luckily that just a single setting and it worked. If you intent to do the encoding manually, I guess I couldn't be your help. And about LSB, google will return a null json response if your pcm file is encoded in MSB.

Comment: Pass -w 0 flags for base64