# How Can I use Speech To Text Google API in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-speech-to-text-api

I tried to use this API and return this error:

> Exception has occurred.
>   DetailedApiRequestError (DetailedApiRequestError(status: 400, message: Invalid value at 'audio.content' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for "/data/user/0/br.com.icourier.mobi/app_flutter/gravacoes/2020-02-03 14:31:42.328870.m4a"))

I tried to speech a path of file - "/data/user/0/br.com.icourier.mobi/app_flutter/gravacoes/2020-02-03 14:31:42.328870.m4a"

Follow my code:

```
  Future<void> audioRecog(dynamic file) {
    clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, _SCOPES).then((http_client) {
      var speech = new SpeechApi(http_client);
      //var fileAudio = new File(file);
      //var newAudio = base64Encode(fileAudio.readAsBytesSync());

      //var audio = rootBundle.load(file);

      print(file);
      File file2 = new File(file); // (1)
      print(file2);
      Uint8List base64Decode(String file) => base64.decode(file);
      print(file);

      final _json = {
        "audio": {
          "content": "$file",
        },
        "config": {
          "enableAutomaticPunctuation": true,
          "encoding": "LINEAR16",
          "languageCode": "pt-BR",
          "model": "default"
        }
      };

      final _recognizeRequest = RecognizeRequest.fromJson(_json);
      speech.speech.recognize(_recognizeRequest).then((response) {
        for (var result in response.results) {
          print(result.toJson());
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: where is the result of your decode op?  if its in base64Decode , then feed that to the API in property="content" ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606167/base64-decoding-failed-for-google-speech-api  its not flutter but it may help u anyway

Comment: I will try to use this now. I will feedback

Comment: Now my problem is:

**I/flutter (22554): reading of bytes is completed
E/flutter (22554): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
E/flutter (22554): Receiver: null
E/flutter (22554): Tried calling: iterator**

Comment: Now I got this error: **[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.**

Comment: not a flutter/dart/java guy but, https://medium.com/google-cloud/getting-started-with-dart-on-gcp-ffc49165d181 you may review the link, run the api from CLI , then go back to your flutter routine.  IMO you need to understand the api and input regarding ( raw_audio, OR audio converted to b64 string ) and u need to understand the value of content property and which of the above types of input is being consumed by the api

Comment: Thats not work for me, still received null.

Comment: Since you're on Flutter, might as well check out this package https://pub.dev/packages/google_speech . Though it's still in development most features have already been built.